# how to use four dropdown lists(country, state, city, pincode)

Tags: drop-down-menu

using dropdown lists(country, state, city) in one table. i want to select one after other like based upon the country, states has to be displayed and based upon the states, cities has to be displayed in asp.net(C#).

Ex: I have a page called company details where I need to enter company Address like country,state,city. now, my requirement is if I select INDIA as Country so all the list of states in INDIA should be displayed in state drop-box from that I should pick one state say Andhra Pradesh if I pick it all the cities in Andhra Pradesh should be displayed in city drop-box.

Comment: (A) Your question is hard to understand (B) you need to explain what you have tried that did not work and importantly (C) there are drop down boxes in so many languages that you need to say which you are using...

Answer (score 0):

You are expecting  multiple dependent select box. Post your code upto what you have tried.

Check the below link to understand how they implemented.
http://demo.rsjoomla.com/dynamic-drop-down-change-form-example

Google "dynamic dropdown select" to see more example.

Hope it helps.

Comment: so far I just had text-box for country,state and city from now I want it should be picked from drop-box items.

Comment: The following link gave me the solution for my requirement.

Comment: http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/rohatash/dropdownlist-with-country-state-and-city-in-asp-net/